# Reference to System.dll is declared but not found - how to solve?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying so solve a Warning in an old asp.net Webapplication.

The warning Shows:

> The Reference of Type System.Collections.Generic.ISet´1 is declared in  "c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" , but couldn't found

Data: System.Core.dll

All the Files are in the folders. I dont know what it means and how I should solve that warning. Anybody got a clue?

Comment: *"Data: System.Core.dll"* what the heck do you mean by that? Anyhow, you need to turn on fusion logging. If I had to guess (what I can't do anything else) go make sure you have .net 2 installed. Open up Windows Features and make sure "Net Framework 3.5 (includes .net 2.0 and 3.0)" is installed.

Comment: In the warning shows also the path c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll <projectname> that i mean with data System.Core.dll.  
I installed 4.5.2 today. So all .net Frameworks should be installed. I will get fusionlog and also show the result soon.

Comment: Please check you have 3.5 installed. CLR 4.5 is a whole new runtime. If you can't or don't want to modify your app to run on a newer framework you need to have the older framework installed too. They can be installed side by side.

Comment: Im working on win 7 sp1. so it should include 3.5 (including 3 and 2) but i also activate  .net 3.5 on Windows Features. Still shows the warning. Dont know how Fusion Log is working. because i got no entry by starting Fusionlog. Maybe something is not working with ASP.Net? Also all registry entrys for fusion log are enable.

Comment: I guess the problem is the changing from .net 3.5 to 4. But it is necessary because of other .dll. When i migrat back to 3.5 more errors occur. So i have to deal with it. it is just a warning. And no sideeffect is shown up yet. thx all for your advices and your time. you are lovley :*